# Help with Pointer Arithmetic

Tags: c++, pointers

I've been studying C++ for a test and I am currently stuck with pointer arithmetic.

The basic problem is the following:

```
int numColumns = 3;
int numRows    = 4;

int a[numRows][numColumns];

a[0][0] = 1;
a[0][1] = 2;
a[0][2] = 3;
a[1][0] = 4;
a[1][1] = 5;
a[1][2] = 6;
a[2][0] = 7;
a[2][1] = 8;
a[2][2] = 9;
a[3][0] = 10;
a[3][1] = 11;
a[3][2] = 12;

for (int i=numColumns-1; i>-1;i--)
{
  cout << a[numRows-1][i] << endl;
}
```

A very simple program which prints the lower "row of the matrix".  i.e. 12,11,10.

Now I am trying to do the equivalent with a int*.

What I have been told by my classmates is to think it like this:

```
array[i][j] == p[numColumns*i+j]
```

If that is correct, shouldn't the following be equivalent to what I'm looking for:

```
int* p = reinterpret_cast<int*> a;
for (int i=numColumns-1; i>-1;i--)
{
  cout << p[numColumns*(numRows-1)+i] << endl;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Thanks for telling us that you were studying for a test.  I added the `homework` tag to your question.  You're asking these in a good way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

int `array[3][5]` is NOT an abstraction (in the C++ language) for `int array[3*5]`.  The standard says that a 2 dimensional array (and N-dimensional arrays in general) are arrays of arrays.  That `array[3][5]` is an array of three elements, where each element is an array containing 5 elements (integers in this case).  C++'s type system does make that distinction.

According to the C++ standard, and array `T array[N]` is a contiguous block of memory containing the N elements of type T.  So that means that a multidimensional array, let's say int array[3][5] will be a continuous block of memory containing 3 `int[5]` arrays, and each `int[5]` array is a contiguous block of 5 `ints`.

On my machine, the memory ends up laid out exactly as you would expect - identical to `int array[3*5]`.  The way the memory is treated is different however, due to the type system (which distinguishes between `int[]` and `int[][]`).  This is why you need to use a `reinterpret_cast` which essentially tells your compiler "take this memory and without doing any conversion, treat it like this new type".

I'm not completely sure if this memory layout is guaranteed however.  I couldn't find anything in the standard stating that arrays can't be padded.  If they can be padded (again, I'm not sure) then it's possible that the `int[5]` array is not actually 5 elements long (a better example would be `char[5]`, which I could see being padded to 8 bytes).

Also there is an appreciable difference between `int*` and `int**` since the latter doesn't guarantee contiguous memory.

EDIT: The reason that C++ distinguishes between `int[3*5]` and `int[3][5]` is because it wants to guarantee the order of the elements in memory.  In C++ `int[0][1]` and `int[0][2]` are `sizeof(int)` apart in memory.  However in Fortran, for example, `int[0][0]` and `int[1][0]` are `sizeof(int)` apart in memory because Fortran uses *column major* representation.

Here's a diagram to help explain:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

Can be made into an array that looks like {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} or an array that looks like: {0,3,6,1,4,7,2,5,8}.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: in your original code, the type of `a` is more similar to `int**`, so you shouldn't cast it to `int*`. It is *a pointer to pointer to* something.

If you want to access it like an 1-D array, then `a` has to be defined as an 1-D array as well.

Comment: Really? I thought that multi-dimensionals arrays were just an "abstraction" for us, since the following is equivalent:

    int array[3][5];
    int array[3*5];

Answer (score 0):

@rwong: Really? I thought that multi-dimensionals arrays were just an "abstraction" for us, since the following are equivalent:

```
int array[3][5];
int array[3*5];
```

Anyways, I detemined what was wrong. As usual it was not my code, but copy-pasting someone's code and working from there.

What I had was this:

```
for(int i=numRows-1; i>-1 ;i++)
{
  cout << p[numColumns*numRows-1+i] << endl;
}
```

Is funny because I did not copy-paste my code from VS, but actually wrote it from scratch to "illustrate" my error.

Lesson to be learnt here ;)

*Edit:  I'm still not sure about what rwong explained here.  Would anyone care to elaborate?*

Comment: I believe you are thinking of regular C, not C++.  In regular C, `int a[rows][cols]; int *b = (int*)a; a[x][y] == b[x*cols + y];` would return true.

Comment: What rwong is saying is that strictly speaking, the `a` in `a[x][y]` is a pointer-to-a-pointer (or `int**`).  An item from the first dimension (`a[x]`) is a `int*`, not necessarily an array.  You can have an array of pointers to dynamically-allocated arrays.  In that case, you can index the "matrix" like `a[x][y]` but the rows are not necessarily contiguous in memory so the syntax `a[x*cols + y]` would most likely not work.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about it: since `a` is similar to an `int**`, is there a part of `a` that's similar to an `int*`?

Comment: wait a min.  Now I'm even more confused.  
<br/>
What I know is that the identifier of an array is equivalent to an address of its first element, so a pointer and an array are the same concept.
<br/>
If this is true, and multi-dimension arrays are just an abstraction for programmers where the compiler remembers the depth of each "dimension", then how can a matrix be equivalent to a int**?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes.  In C++ int[][] is not an abstraction for int[].  int[][] is its own type.  The reason is that C++ is a row major language.  int[] allows you to use row or column major layouts.  For example, you can do p[y*width+x] (row major) or p[x*height+y] (column major).  In C++ int[x][y] is always p[y*width+x].